# How to perform an "all" operation on an arbitrary number of Bool Publishers in Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I've got a situation where I'm trying to determine if an arbitrary number of boolean checks (user defined conditionals) are `true`. It seems like a job for CombineLatest combined with AllSatisfy... the problem being that CombineLatest only supports a fixed number of elements (2, 3 or 4). Is there some pattern other than using repeated 2-element CombineLatest publishers which combine each result with another of the publishers?

Ideally, I'd like something along the lines of:

`Publishers.CombineLatestMany(arrayOfPublishers).allSatisfy { ... }`

and not:

`Publishers.CombineLatest(pubA, pubB).combineLatest(pubC).combineLatest(pubD) ...`

Comment: The boolean checks are publishers that produce a boolean result based on some upstream work. I don't know how many of them there will be at runtime.

Comment: The publishers can vary from true to false and back freely based on user actions. I'm interested in observing when all of them are true and taking action only then.

Comment: Are these "publishers" things with states, like switches? If so, it doesn't sound like a case for Combine at all. If not, and you want to use Combine, then it does sound a job for CombineLatest and the answer you've been given is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your need, unless your publishers are of different types:

```
extension Publisher where Output == Bool {
    func and<P: Publisher>(_ rest: P...) -> some Publisher where P.Output == Output, P.Failure == Failure {
        rest.reduce(AnyPublisher(self)) { acc, next in
            AnyPublisher(acc.combineLatest(next).map { $0 && $1 })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just `map(&&)` btw

Comment: You can't use `map(&&)` because `&&`'s right argument is an `@autoclosure`.

Comment: Ahhh, true. Though Idk why you're being downvotes :/